# Launching Gallery from Camera

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, android-gallery

How does the Camera application in Nexus 5 (Google Camera) launch Gallery when we swipe left? Is it Intent based? How do they get the smooth transition? I want to get the same behaviour in my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @Raptor I'm using Intent to launch the 2nd Activity. But the transition is not smooth. Note that I have no control over the 2nd Activity's code.

Answer (score 0):

To get smooth activity transitions you can use [custom animations](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions) and call `overridePendingTransition` immediately after `startActivity`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(
    R.anim.right_to_left_slide_in,
    R.anim.right_to_left_slide_out);
```

Comment: I'm already using custom animations. But the problem here is that the second activity is not part of my application. I'm using intent.setClassName() to set the package name and class to launch a 3rd party Activity.

Comment: I have tried the same code. The slide in animation should move with the swipe (Like Google Camera and Gallery). I can't achieve that behaviour with these transitions.